# How to avoid two files in project view when creating a custom importer in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

**NOTE:** I'm casting a wider net than Unity Answers, my original question can be found [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/955167/how-to-avoid-two-files-in-project-view-when-creati.html).

I've created a ProTools CueSheet importer. It uses `OnPostprocessAllAssets()` to detect a files in the project that have a `.cuesheet` extension. It then runs those cuesheet files through my parser. This generates a ScriptableObject which is then turned into an asset via `Database.CreateAsset()`.

The problem is, this leaves me with two files, the original cuesheet and the newly generated asset. Is there any way I can generate the asset in such as way that the original cuesheet acts as the asset, the same way textures or FBX files do?

```
public class CueSheetPostProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {
    static string extension = ".cuesheet";

    static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(string[] importedAssets, string[] deletedAssets, string[] movedAssets, string[] movedFromAssetPaths) {
        foreach (string assetPath in importedAssets) {
            if (assetPath.EndsWith(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                string newPath = assetPath + ".asset";
                Session session = CueImporter.Load(assetPath);
                AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(session, newPath);
                AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this is not possible, but I'm not 99% sure. Having two files at once may be inconvenient, but are there any major drawbacks?

Comment: @golergka It confuses what's an asset and what's a source file. Plenty of core types such as FBX, WAV, MP3, etc. all are converted in place. There isn't an asset next to an FBX, for example. There's some very slight documentation about these being called "representations". I'm trying to determine if this is possible with custom formats, but I can't justify downloading hundreds of dollars worth of importers on the Unity Asset Store to dig through their source just to find out.

Comment: When Unity imports Assets, it creates the file it actually uses in the Library folder under the project. If you have a look at the .meta files that belongs for example to a WAV (set it to text in the project settings if it shows at binary), you will find a guid there and you will find a file named as the guid in the Library folder. Maybe you can do the same with your importer?

Comment: As far as I know, the Library folder is just the project's cache. It's where the optimized versions of the wav or png are stored. Developers have no control over the Library folder; Unity manages it completely.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `PropertyDrawer` for the `Serializable` class `CueSheet` such that it accepts the `.cueSheet TextAsset` or path to the `.cueSheet` file and create an instance of the class `CueSheet` and assign it or modify it.

Comment: This sounds promising. Are there any references you could recommend for this?

Comment: I've looked into this and it's really just an inspector enhancement. Is this actually how Unity handles importing FBX files, audio and textures?

Comment: I don't know if it is the same way as unity handles it, but it can give you prefab like behaviour, similar to unity's prefab.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a new asset, have you tried using AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset instead? An file in Assets can "hold" multiple assets and multiple asset types. When importing a .fbx, the output in the project inspector is several things: a GameObject tree (ie, a prefab), some models, maybe a rig, and so on. All these are "contained" in the processed .fbx